# MPJ Express Scatterv and Gatherv, what is the purpose of int[] displacement?

Tags: c++, mpi, java

Question #1.

What is the purpose of the "displacements" parameter for Scatterv? and how does it differ from Gatherv? and how it support against "overlapping" on the address space? and what does your average joe displacement array look like?

```
Scatterv( Object sendbuf, int sendoffset, int[] sendcounts,
int[] displs, Datatype sendtype, Object recvbuf,
int recvoffset, int recvcount, Datatype recvtype,
int root )

Gatherv( Object sendbuf, Object sendbuf, int sendoffset,
int sendcount, Datatype sendtype, Object recvbuf,
int[] recvcounts, int[] displs, Datatype recvtype,
int root )
```

Question #2.

In Gatherv which of the two **sendbuf** parameters are receiving or sending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1. The purpose of the dispacements and the counts is the same in both the scatter vector and the gather vector operations. Both specify the position in the big buffer (`sendbuf` in scatter, `recvbuf` in gather) from where each data block starts and how much elements it is. In `Scatterv` these are used to define the blocks from the `sendbuf` that are to be scattered to all processes in the communicator. In `Gatherv` these are used to define where in the `recvbuf` to put the different pieces of data comming from all processes in the communicator. The MPI standard mandates that **no single location should be read more than once during scatter and no single location should be written more than once during gather**, i.e. the individual blocks should not overlap, but for performance reasons most (if not all) existing MPI implementations do not enforce strictly that constraint. The average Joe displacement array looks different depending on what Joe does in his MPI code. Since `Scatterv` and `Gatherv` are mostly used to enable scattering and gathering of data when its number of elements is not divisible by the number of processes in the communicator, in most cases `displs[0] = 0` and `displs[i] = sendcounts[0] + sendcounts[1] + ... + sendcounts[i-1]` (or `recvcounts` respectively).

Q2. `sendbuf`, `sendoffset` and `sendcount` specify the local portion of the data to be gathered. `recvbuf`, `recvcounts[]` and `displs[]` specify the portions in the big buffer where those local pieces are to be gathered.

It's all written in the MPI standard, which IMHO is one of the few standards that are readable by mere mortals.

Comment: Thank you so much hristo! :) massive help